# Mouse movement on Synergy-controlled PC is slow/laggy?

Tags: synergy

**Update:** They fixed the macOS wifi lag on Synergy 1.9.0! https://symless.com/forums/topic/2587-download-synergy-190-to-fix-the-wifi-macos-bug/

I'm not sure why this started happening. I just started using Synergy again to control my laptop using my desktop's keyboard and mouse, and the cursor (when accessing my laptop) is incredibly laggy, jumpy, etc. (and it wasn't like this before). Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Comment: Can you do a `ping` from your desktop to your laptop to find the network latency?

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping 192.168.254.2
Pinging 192.168.254.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Not sure why it's timing out, Synergy works, it's just laggy as hell.

Comment: Ping is probably being blocked by Windows Firewall, try disabling it temporarily and run ping again.

Comment: @mtak Pinging Craig-Notebook [192.168.254.2] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.254.2: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.254.2: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.254.2: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.254.2: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=64

Comment: It's using my wifi download/upload rather than network download/upload is what I'm noticing. Maybe that helps?

Comment: Did it go away when you restart the client as in this [comment](http://superuser.com/users/46328/maqleod)?

Comment: **This is fixed!** We fixed the macOS wifi lag on Synergy 1.9.0!

Comment: I'm using 1.10 version and it still laggy, but I changed log level from `info` to `warning` and it looks good so far~

Answer (score 0):

the fix that worked for me was to restart the client machine. My suspicion is that gradually there is a build up of routes and connections that a dns flush doesn't fix. My setup is a mac client and a linux server.

Comment: "build up of routes and connections that a dns flush doesn't fix" - this isn't how networking works...this statement is mixing several concepts that are not really related.

Comment: Turning off bluetooth on my mac was very helpful for me.

Comment: *This is fixed!* We fixed the macOS wifi lag on Synergy 1.9.0! https://symless.com/forums/topic/2587-download-synergy-190-to-fix-the-wifi-macos-bug/

Comment: I am still facing this these days, here I show how to fix it.
First, kill your synergy process by: `pkill synergy`. Then, re-run synergy daemon in your client ID (i am using ubuntu 16.04) by: `synergyc [SERVER_ID]`. It works for me.